# Magento SOAP API forgot password webservice implementation

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am using Magento SOAP API v2 for web services. It doesn’t support default Customer forgot password API.

Any one can provide me details how can I create the forgot password API and mail send in Magento?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Magento admin panel System->Web Service-> SOAP/XML-RPC - Users and SOAP/XML-RPC - Role

Create the rol an the user to the api magento

Comment: I have already done this settings, and make other APIs, I am asking for customer forgot password API.